# How to effectively connect to Bluetooth Device socket with Android Java?

Tags: java, c#, android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my bluetooth app to my PC using Android Java. After I have connected my app to the PC socket then I can send a message such as `Say Hello`. My app is successful in scanning for Bluetooth Devices in range using the location and bluetooth API. It discovers my PC and I grab the UUID of my PC from the Bluetooth Device profile discovered for my PC. I expose the UUID of my PC as a Bluetooth Device on the logcat and it looks like `device.getUUIDs` does not return null as long as you cancel discovery before calling it. Here is the UUID string printed on my logcat

```
BluetoothClient.BluetoothClient D/UUID: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

The code below shows how I attempt to connect to the PC Bluetooth device socket

```
//check if the device is already bonded and attempt to connect to its socket if it is exposed
 if (dev.BondState == Bond.Bonded){
  //device is a bluetooth device on my list I grabbed from the broadcast receiver
  //grab the UUID of the discovered bluetooth device
  UUID MYUUID = dev.GetUuids()[0].Uuid;
  //create a bluetooth socket using the UUID for connection purposes
  BluetoothSocket socket = dev.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MYUUID);
  //connect to the socket
  socket.Connect();
 }
```

The code written does not throw any exceptions nor does the app crash, this information is printed on my logcat.

```
 D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
 // I do not know what the above is and what device is null 
 I/BluetoothSocket: connect() for device F894C2 called by pid: 2822
 W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
 //if a bluetooth manager callback is needed for the socket creation, how do attach the callback to my code to make this work, Thank You.
```

Comment: This works for me: mmSocket = bluedev.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                  UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));  
mmSocket.connect();                  
instream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
outstream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();

Comment: Maybe the problem is the service UUID. 0000110a is an audio link. You need 00001101 for a serial port. Running a Bluetooth server terminal on the PC should set one up, or See sections 5.4.1, 5.4.2 and 5.5.3 in the documentation here for bare-bones code to set up an Android/Windows serial link https://github.com/petzval/btferret

Comment: @petzval, hey okay should I try exposing other UUIDs on the device to see if I will get a non-audio UUID?

Comment: Can I use the hardcoded UUID you used in the first comment?

Comment: Almost certainly - that is the standard UUID for a serial port

Comment: Okay thanks trying that out, what about this logcat info `isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null`, does it have something to do with UUID?

Comment: @petzval, you saved me. Your UUID works, will it work for other android devices?

Comment: Any device with a serial service will almost certainly accept that standard UUID, but some such as the Windows COM port may only accept the 2-byte version 1101.

Comment: @petzval, can you edit now to post an answer on how to check if the socket is connected and then send message `Say Hello` to bluetooth device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 5.5.3 in the README.md documentation here for bare-bones code https://github.com/petzval/btferret.
The functions instream.read and outstream.write exchange serial data.

```
 byte[] dat;
 String s;
 int len;

 dat = new byte[32];
 s = "Hello\n";
 len = s.length();
 for(n = 0 ; n < len ;++n)
   dat[n] = s.charAt(n);
 
 outstream.write(dat,0,len);
```

Comment: Your repository is in C, can you post an answer in android java please

Comment: Sections 5.4.3 and 5.5.3 are Android Java code - everything else is C.

Comment: I have tested your UUID against an array of Android devices and it works, good work

Comment: Hey your UUID for the server code is throwing this error `Invalid UUID string: FCF05AFD-67D8-4F41-83F57BEE22C03CDB`

Comment: The UUID is your free choice. See section 5.1 in the documentation for a description of how UUIDs relate to RFCOMM serial channels. If in doubt, use the standard UUID.

Comment: Is it okay to use random UUID for server? because that is what I did in my server app

Comment: I use a random UUID without any problem, as long as the client knows about it. But there may be fussy systems which insist on a standard RFCOMM UUID which starts 00001101.